# How can I seal doors and windows to keep air out?

Tags: windows

My problem is that my door has a wide crack under it. It lets in insects and lets out the air or heat. I know you can use a foam seal but need something to go all around the door. I haven't tried any thing yet because I dont know what to start. Can anyone provide a suggestion for the method I should use?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [threshold](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Frost-King-E-O-3-1-2-in-Wide-x-36-in-Silver-Adjustable-Height-Threshold-DAT39H/100121731?N=5yc1vZc3e9) to the door to seal under it.  There a number of thresholds where you can then adjust the height to meet the bottom of the door.  Around the other 3 sides you need to add weather [stripping](http://www.homedepot.com/p/MD-Building-Products-Door-Jamb-Weather-Strip-Kit-49002/100353438).

Answer (score 0):

if you are not allowed to add anything to the door you can buy a long [round cushion](https://www.google.be/search?q=draft%20cushion&num=100&tbm=isch) that you put in front of the door (or train your dog to do that :) )

If you are allowed to add something to the door you can install a sweep:

[image: as found on google]

Comment: That doesn't look like it would block air movement like a compressible gasket would.

Comment: A brush-style sweep does help reduce airflow, though it isn't a gasketed seal. There are variants which have multiple plastic ridges or other protrusions that attempt to achieve a better seal; I'm not sure whether they actually work significantly better.